# How to get total count of given weeks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a query that the `weekofyear` returned with a value if there are 4 or more `DISTINCT(DELIVERYDATE)` in that week.  Therefore, if there only 3 days, it would return a null value.  If 4 or more `DISTINCT(DELIVERYDATE)` then return 'weekofyear' value.

```
SELECT  READYDATE,TOTALAMOUNT,ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER,
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),LEFT(DELIVERYDATE,4))  + '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART( wk, DELIVERYDATE))) AS WEEKOfYear
FROM CurrentOrder  COrder
WHERE
  COrder.CANCELLED = 0 
  AND COrder.DELIVERYDATE>='20171116'
  AND COrder.DELIVERYDATE<='20171116'
  ORDER BY DISPID
```

Expected Output that I want as a result of the query

```
READYDATE   TOTALAMOUNT ORDERNUM    DELIVERYDATE WEEKOfYear  
2017-11-16  11.24       6784230     2017-11-16  201746   
2017-11-16  0.00        6788903     2017-11-16  201746   
2017-11-16  91.85       6789075S    2017-11-16  201746   
2017-11-16  640.00      6789080S    2017-11-16  201746   
2017-11-16  0.00        6789213S    2017-11-16  201746   
2017-11-15  0.00        6789098S    2017-11-15  NULL     
2017-11-15  0.00        6789103S    2017-11-15  NULL     
2017-11-15  0.00        6789110S    2017-11-15  NULL     
2017-11-13  250.00      6789751S    2017-11-13  NULL     
2017-11-13  250.00      6789756S    2017-11-13  NULL     
2017-11-13  25.00       6789773S    2017-11-13  NULL     
2017-11-14  242.00      6789779S    2017-11-14  201746   
2017-11-14  23.88       6789816S    2017-11-14  201746   
2017-11-14  190.00      6789833S    2017-11-14  201746   
2017-11-14  215.00      6789845S    2017-11-14  201746   
2017-11-14  108.00      6789873S    2017-11-14  201746

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CurrentOrder](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TOTALAMOUNT] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
    [READYDATE] [date] NULL,
    [DELIVERYDATE] [date] NULL,
    [CANCELLED] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DispID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

    INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (1, N'6784230', CAST(11.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), 0, 56)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (2, N'6788903', CAST(0.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), 0, 56)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (3, N'6789075S', CAST(92.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), 0, 56)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (4, N'6789080S', CAST(640.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), 0, 56)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (5, N'6789213S', CAST(0.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x883D0B00 AS Date), 0, 56)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (6, N'6789098S', CAST(0.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), 0, 66)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (7, N'6789103S', CAST(0.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), 0, 66)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (8, N'6789110S', CAST(0.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x873D0B00 AS Date), 0, 66)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (9, N'6789751S', CAST(250.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), 0, 65)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (10, N'6789756S', CAST(250.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), 0, 65)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (11, N'6789773S', CAST(25.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x853D0B00 AS Date), 0, 65)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (12, N'6789779S', CAST(242.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), 0, 39)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (13, N'6789816S', CAST(24.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), 0, 39)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (14, N'6789833S', CAST(190.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), 0, 39)
INSERT [dbo].[CurrentOrder] ([OrderId], [ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER], [TOTALAMOUNT], [READYDATE], [DELIVERYDATE], [CANCELLED], [DispID]) VALUES (15, N'6789845S', CAST(215.0000000000 AS Decimal(18, 10)), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x863D0B00 AS Date), 0, 39)
```

Description :- DeliveryDate - `2017-11-16` is more than 4 so that is displaying the value in `WEEKOfYear` but for DeliveryDate '2017-11-15`has only three orders so this is displaying Null same as for the date`2017-11-13`. But again DELIVERDATE`2017-11-14` have more than 4 order for that date so this is displaying the WEEKOfYear.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML (create table + insert into statements) and desired results.

Comment: Is a delivery date any week-day?  If you want to exclude bank holidays etc you could add a [calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) to your db.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i have added output that i want with DDL + DML

Comment: Your sample data does not match the query - the `Canceled` and `DISPID` columns are missing from your sample data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i have updated the sample table with data plz take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses a [common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to find each delivery date with 4 or more records.  Using the delivery date it calculates the week of year.  We can then use an [outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins) to append the new field to every matching record in the original table.

```
WITH DWeek AS
(
    -- Calculate week of year for every delivery date with 4 or more records.
    SELECT
        DELIVERYDATE,
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),LEFT(DELIVERYDATE,4))  + '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART( wk, DELIVERYDATE))) AS WEEKOfYear
    FROM
        CurrentOrder
    WHERE
        DELIVERYDATE IS NOT NULL
        AND CANCELLED = 0 
        AND DELIVERYDATE >= '20171114'
        AND DELIVERYDATE <= '20171116'
    GROUP BY    
        DELIVERYDATE
    HAVING
        COUNT(1) >= 4
)
SELECT
    co.*,
    s.WEEKOfYear
FROM
    CurrentOrder AS co
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DWeek AS s     ON s.DELIVERYDATE = co.DELIVERYDATE
;
```

Returns

```
OrderId ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER  TOTALAMOUNT     READYDATE   CANCELLED   DELIVERYDATE    WEEKOfYear
1       6784230             11.2400000000   2017-11-16  0           2017-11-16      201746
2       6788903             0.0000000000    2017-11-16  0           2017-11-16      201746
3       6789075S            91.8500000000   2017-11-16  0           2017-11-16      201746
4       6789080S            640.0000000000  2017-11-16  0           2017-11-16      201746
5       6789213S            0.0000000000    2017-11-16  0           2017-11-16      201746
6       6789098S            0.0000000000    2017-11-15  0           2017-11-15      NULL
7       6789103S            0.0000000000    2017-11-15  0           2017-11-15      NULL
8       6789110S            0.0000000000    2017-11-15  0           2017-11-15      NULL
9       6789751S            250.0000000000  2017-11-13  0           2017-11-13      NULL
10      6789756S            250.0000000000  2017-11-13  0           2017-11-13      NULL
11      6789773S            25.0000000000   2017-11-13  0           2017-11-13      NULL
12      6789779S            242.0000000000  2017-11-14  0           2017-11-14      201746
13      6789816S            23.8800000000   2017-11-14  0           2017-11-14      201746
14      6789833S            190.0000000000  2017-11-14  0           2017-11-14      201746
15      6789845S            215.0000000000  2017-11-14  0           2017-11-14      201746
```

**EDIT**

My original answer missed a number of important details from the OP.  This is a totally reworked answer.

Comment: thanks but where i will use WHERE clause `COrder.CANCELLED = 0 `
 ` AND COrder.DELIVERYDATE>='20171116'`
 ` AND COrder.DELIVERYDATE<='20171116'`

Comment: but WEEKOfYear  is important if the same date data have 4 times or more than 4 time than this will display WEEKOfYear  otherwise this will display null see my example above that i provide

Comment: `2017-11-14` no longer appears in the answer, as the where clause removes these records.  The examples no longer work with your DDL, as `CurrentOrder` does not include a `CANCELLED` column.

Comment: Ohh sorry i made mistake i have not provide cancel in that

Comment: It's easy to add `WEEKofYear` back in.  See updated answer.

Comment: i think i missed to type in my question the weekOfyear is important when the DELIVERYDATE is more than than 4 then it will display the weekofyear otherwise in WeekofYear will show null

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count()` with `over()` clause to get the number of rows per delivery date, and a case to determine whether to show the weekOfYear or null, like this:

```
SELECT  READYDATE,
        TOTALAMOUNT,
        ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER, 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY DELIVERYDATE) > 3 THEN
            CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DELIVERYDATE) as char(4)) +
            CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, DELIVERYDATE) as char(2))
        ELSE
            NULL
        END As WeekOfYear
FROM CurrentOrder
WHERE CANCELLED = 0 
ORDER BY DISPID
```

Results:

```
READYDATE       TOTALAMOUNT         ORDER_TRACK_NUMBER  WeekOfYear
2017-11-14      242,0000000000      6789779S            201746
2017-11-14      24,0000000000       6789816S            201746
2017-11-14      190,0000000000      6789833S            201746
2017-11-14      215,0000000000      6789845S            201746
2017-11-16      11,0000000000       6784230             201746
2017-11-16      0,0000000000        6788903             201746
2017-11-16      92,0000000000       6789075S            201746
2017-11-16      640,0000000000      6789080S            201746
2017-11-16      0,0000000000        6789213S            201746
2017-11-13      250,0000000000      6789751S            NULL
2017-11-13      250,0000000000      6789756S            NULL
2017-11-13      25,0000000000       6789773S            NULL
2017-11-15      0,0000000000        6789098S            NULL
2017-11-15      0,0000000000        6789103S            NULL
2017-11-15      0,0000000000        6789110S            NULL
```

Comment: i think your query is missing the week start date. If you take a look the question you missed this part ` there are 4 or more DISTINCT(DELIVERYDATE) in that week. Therefore, if there only 3 days, it would return a null value.`

Comment: the in the calculation the more important is calculate the data by the week. So first i think we need to know weekstart date and week end date

Comment: I went by your desired output. It doesn't fit the text requirement. It's impossible for `2017-11-15` to return NULL if you are counting the number of rows on a weekly bases since both it's consecutive dates returns data. The 15th has to be either in the same week as the 14th or the same week as the 16th or the same week as both.

Comment: i created the solution for my above question. But issue with the performance of i create a new question plz take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204116

Answer (score 0):

This will give outpt mentioned in your desired result :-

```
select mastr.* , case when mastr.deliverydate = del.deliverydate then  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),LEFT(mastr.DELIVERYDATE,4))  + '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART( wk, mastr.DELIVERYDATE)))  else null end as 'WeekOfYear' from
    [dbo].[CurrentOrder] mastr 
    left join 
        (Select distinct deliverydate from 
            (select deliverydate, rank() over(partition by deliverydate order by orderid) as cnt 
            from [dbo].[CurrentOrder] where [CANCELLED] = 0) ranked
        Where cnt > 3) del
    on mastr.deliverydate = del.deliverydate
```