# Decrease the execution time of the query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I write a query the result of the query is fine but issue with the time that is taking to complete the execution. For increase the performance i create index as per my query so this decrease from 5 minutes to 0.44 seconds. But i want to make this more faster. The issue i release with my function that i comment then its execution time is 0.00 but the function i am using is important for me. Is any option to decrease my execution time of my query .

**My function*

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCount]

(

      @StartDate DATE,@EndDate DATE,@DropDate DATE

)

RETURNS INT     
AS    
BEGIN    
      DECLARE @WeekStartDate DATE    
      DECLARE @WeekEndDate DATE    
      DECLARE @Count AS INT    
      SET @Count=0    
      SET @WeekStartDate=CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @DropDate)-1), @DropDate))    
      SET @WeekEndDate=CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @DropDate)), @DropDate))          

      IF @StartDate <= @WeekStartDate    
            SET @StartDate=@WeekStartDate    
      IF @EndDate >=@WeekEndDate    
            SET @EndDate=@WeekEndDate  
      SELECT @Count=COUNT(distinct DROPDATE)    
      FROM  orde_    
      WHERE  orde_.CANCELLED = 0     
      AND DROPDATE >= @StartDate AND DROPDATE <= @EndDate    
      AND (DISPID IS NULL OR DISPID NOT IN ( '291', '327') )    
      RETURN @Count

END
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT READYDATE,TOTAL,DRV1PAY,ORDERNUM,
CASE WHEN dbo.fnCount('20170901','20171031',DROPDATE) >=4
THEN  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),LEFT(DROPDATE,4))  + '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART( wk, DROPDATE)))
ELSE NULL
END AS WEEKOfYear1,
FROM  orde_
WHERE  CANCELLED = 0  AND DROPDATE >='20170901'  AND DROPDATE <='20171031'
AND (DISPID IS NULL OR DISPID NOT IN ( '291', '327') )
ORDER BY DISPID
```

Thanks for your help and comments

Comment: *Change* the function, simplify the entire query. Your "function" is actually a full query on top of the same table you use for the *outer* query. There are a lot of needles string conversions and date operations which make it hard to understand what the two queries do. *What* do the queries do? It'll be a lot easier to come up with a single query that does that instead of trying to reverse-engineer what each one does.

Comment: For example, your `fnCount` query counts queries insided a date range while the outer query returns values outside that range. Sounds a lot like a sefl join or a subquery. Or you may need a CTE to create intermediate results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The function i created is used for calculating how many distinct dropdate for that week, So i am using this function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can i accomplish the same with CTE that reduce the time for the query

Comment: As I said, explain what the queries are supposed to do. The queries don't make much sense right now. Don't call `fnCount` it a *function*, because it's a full-blown query repeated for each row of the outer query. You have to eliminate this but first, explain what you actually want to do, not how you think it would look like. What is the business logic? What week are you talking about? The one specified by the hard-coded dates?

Comment: I agree - explain what you're actually trying to do because it can probably be rewritten without a function. If you are counting weeks then a calendar table may help a lot here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i write this query to do for this solution-  I only want the weekofyear returned with a value if there are 4 or more DISTINCT(DROPDATE) in that week.  Therefore, if there only 3 days, it would return a null value.  If 4 or more DISTINCT(DROPDATE) then return weekofyear value.

Comment: I was ready to propose a calendar table too. You could create a calendar table with the year, month, week for each date. This would allow you to group by the year & week columns to get counts per week. Or you could use a `COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY Calendar.WeekNum)` to get the week total on every row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comment, I never used this can you please tell me how can I achieve this. Because i try to achieve the goal from last 3 days but last i get above solution with slow process

Comment: @A.Goutam you are still describing your code, not the actual business problem. And the current issue is the existence of `fnCount` itself. *Maybe* it can be replaced with `COUNT(DISTINCT DROPDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART( wk,DROPDATE)` but I suspect performance wouldn't be that great. The server would have to scan the table twice to partition rows by week. That's why you need the calendar table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes because DROPDATE in order table and i need to count how much dropdate in the week so it is scaning twice and result is slow

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have problem to count the distinct Dropdate in one week. For this the Dropdate that i am getting from select statement i pass with the user input start date and end date for the period the user wants to check data. The user provided start and end date i count total count of distinct Dropdate for every weeek that is in the user start date and end date. Just for this i am using function

Comment: You _almost_ described the business problem but then you lapsed into just explaining your function again. To put it another way - show some sample input data and output data. Describe how it is transformed. Again I'm fairly certain this can be written without a function